# JointJs port label text font

Tags: jointjs

[Image of model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agBhR.png) I want to decrease the font of port label.

model.addPorts([
{
group: "out",
id: "out",
attrs: {
label: {
text: "out",
},
},
},
]);

simply i want to decrease the size of "in" and "out" text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fontSize` to decrease the size of the text.

In the example you provided, you could do:

```
model.addPorts([ { group: "out", id: "out", attrs: { label: { text: "out", fontSize: 10 }, }, }, ]);
```